# Fetching in react native true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Fetch id is working, but I need more fetching to be done:

1. Product name
2. Total products in store
3. And a few more

I need to get the rest working as well. Can someone help me out? Thank you!

I tried a few things myself but did not get it working.

Or maybe I should use a different approach!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Alert } from 'react-native';

import Header from './components/Header';
import {getBrood} from './api/brood';


export default class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    isLoading: true,
    data: null
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  getBrood().then(data =>{
    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      data: data
    });
  }, error => {

  }
)
}


render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header title="Custom size cms"/>
        <View style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 10 }}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: 'https://cdna.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/005/394/176/large/bram-van-vliet-low-poly-trees-lars-mezaka-3-001.jpg?1490717914'}}/>
        <Text>ID:{this.state.data}</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
  );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  image: {
    width: 180,
    height: 180,
    marginTop: 10
  }
});
```

> Front end

```
import { url, username, password, id } from './config';

export async function getBrood() {

  try{
     let data = await fetch(`${url}${id}?consumer_key=${username}&consumer_secret=${password}`);

     let result = await data.json();
     data = null;
     return result.id

  } catch (error){
    throw error;
  }
}
```

> Back end

[image: Front end Working Id:]

I can only do one fetch at the moment, only the id. The rest is not working...

return.result.id

If I change the (return.result.id) to data ill get no output:
[image]

> I need id,name,price,status

Comment: unclear what is the problem

Comment: Just fetch from the product endpoint or what is the problem ?

Comment: just return result from backend not result.id   then display ID: this.state.data.id, or Name:this.state.data.name etc.

Comment: @NijatAliyev that don't work: the error I got is TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating'this.state.data.id'

Comment: @HaykShakhbazyan I got an API from where I want to get a few data stings from. I managed to just get one fetch working... but I need 5 things from the api

Comment: Remove data=null try again

Comment: let result = await data.json() then console.log(result) and look at what is happening and what returns

Comment: You must be wait loading too... if loading false then display this.state.data.id or other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I fixed it on my own I started playing and fooling with the debugger I will open a new question because I got in my fetch a ID so I can get one product now I need to get a flat list of 5 products**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Alert } from 'react-native';

import Header from './components/Header';
import {getBrood} from './api/brood';

export default class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    isLoading: true,
    id: null,
    name: null,
    price: null
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  getBrood().then(data =>{
    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      id: data.id,
      name: data.name,
      price: data.price,
      Voorraad: data.stock_quantity

    });
  }, error => {

  }
)
}


render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header title="Custom size cms"/>
        <View style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 10 }}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: 'https://cdna.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/005/394/176/large/bram-van-vliet-low-poly-trees-lars-mezaka-3-001.jpg?1490717914'}}/>
        <Text>ID: {this.state.id}</Text>
        <Text>Name: {this.state.name}</Text>
        <Text>Price: {this.state.price}</Text>
        <Text>Voorraad: {this.state.Voorraad}</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
  );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  image: {
    width: 180,
    height: 180,
    marginTop: 10
  }
});
```

> front end

```
import { url, username, password, id, products } from './config';

export async function getBrood() {
  const res = await fetch(`${url}${products}${id}?consumer_key=${username}&consumer_secret=${password}`)
  let data  =  await res.json();
  return data;
}
```

> Back end

[image]

> Results

Answer (score 0):

If this API call is returning multiple items, then you'll need to loop it

```
render() {
  return this.state.data.map(function(res) {
     return (
       <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header title="Custom size cms"/>
        <View style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 10 }}>
          <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: 'https://cdna.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/005/394/176/large/bram-van-vliet-low-poly-trees-lars-mezaka-3-001.jpg?1490717914'}}/>
          <Text>ID:{res.id}</Text>
        </View>
       </View>
     );
   })
}
```

**Update:** 
I see that you need name, price, etc.. Just add `res.name` for the name

Take a look at this example for more understanding **https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html**

Comment: That was not working for me becuase of the back end, I goy it working. I posted my own anwser. (Now I need to fetch a list with more thane one product ill start a new ask post tonight)

Answer (score 0):

Return the fields you want from fetch, also if you only throw from the catch there is no need to wrap it in a try / catch

```js
export async function getBrood() {
  const data = await fetch(`${url}${id}?consumer_key=${username}&consumer_secret=${password}`)
  const { id, name, price, status } = await data.json()
  return { id, name, price, status }
}
```

Update the state with the data

```js
componentDidMount() {
  getBrood()
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        data,
      })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // do something when error occurs
      // dont forget to set isLoading to false
      this.setState({ isLoading: false })
    })
}
```

Now you will be able to access the data through `this.state.data.id/name/price/status`

Note that you cant access the data before the request finishes so you will need to add a check to see if its not loading and this.state.data is not null in case of an error

```js
render() {
  const { isLoading, data } = this.state
  const { id, name, price, status } = data || {}
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Header title="Custom size cms"/>
      <View style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 10 }}>
      <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: 'https://cdna.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/005/394/176/large/bram-van-vliet-low-poly-trees-lars-mezaka-3-001.jpg?1490717914'}}/>
      {isLoading && <Text>Loading...</Text>}
      {data && (
        <>
          <Text>ID: {id}</Text>
          <Text>Name: {name}</Text>
          <Text>Price: {price}</Text>
          <Text>Status: {status}</Text>
        </>
      )}
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: I got no errors But the id,name,price and status are empty .. with     console.log({id}); ```object { "id": undefined }``` if I change the background in  ```import { url, username, password, id, products } from './config';

export async function getBrood() {
  const res = await fetch(`${url}${products}${id}?consumer_key=${username}&consumer_secret=${password}`)
  let data  =  await res.json();
  console.log(data);
}
``` it give me output in the log